# C# PrivateFontCollection AddFontFile from relative path

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, fonts, privatefontcollection

I have OpenSans-Light.ttf in the this folder from root: ~/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf

```
PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
privateFontCollection.AddFontFile("~/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf");
```

but I get "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File not found"

How do I target that font file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution using MapPath:

```
PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
privateFontCollection.AddFontFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf"));
```